# Imageview wrap at bottom and right position in android

Tags: android

I have implemented the the tag image in my app.If i touch inside the layout tag image get visible.That tag images are not wrap at left and Top position.But it will be wrap on right and bottom position.What to do for implementing the tag image without wrapping on right and bottom position.The first image shows without wrapping if i touch any place on left side.In second image the tag gets wrap on right side.`

```
rr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tagimages);
    rr.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    searchlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    int x1 = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp.setMargins(x1, y, 0, 0);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 100);

                        params.topMargin = y;
                        params.leftMargin = x1;
                        params.bottomMargin = 0;
                        params.rightMargin = 0;
                        //rr.setEnabled(false);

                    if(tag1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        tag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rr.removeView(tag1);
                        rr.addView(tag1, params);
                    }
                    else if(tag1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && tag2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        if(!tag1.getText().equals("Who's this?")){
                            tag2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            rr.removeView(tag2);
                            rr.addView(tag2, params);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(tag1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && tag2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ){
                        Toast.makeText(Tagpeople.this, "Maximum of 2 people can be tagged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                    tag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if(tag1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                                tag1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                namelist.remove(tag1.getText().toString());
                                idlist.remove(id1);
                                xlist.remove(xaxis1);
                                ylist.remove(yaxis1);
                                tag1.setText("Who's this?");
                                rr.removeView(tag1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

This is layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/wholelayouttag1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.cogzidel.hotfuse.Tagpeople">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchlayout"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Search friends"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelsearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#0039cf"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tagimages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:background="@drawable/cam"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Who's this?"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/tag1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_tag_show"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_xout"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Who's this?"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_tag_show"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tag1"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_xout"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tag2" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`[image: This position is correct the tag image not wrap on left side]

[image: The tag image is wrap on right side.so i need tag image to displayed like as left side]

Comment: tag1 and tag 2 is not a class its just a textview

Comment: If i touch any left corner position the background image does not cutoff but on right side that tag background gets cutoff so i want that image to be displayed as like a left position if i touch right corner position.i don't want the image to be cutoff at the end of right corner.